# Import data from google drive to Kaggle Kernel

Tags: data, kaggle

I want to import a csv file from google drive . I tried using the link in add dataset tab but it is taking some thing else as "Open". Please see the image.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

1. Go to your Google Drive and right click the dataset you want to upload to Kaggle.
2. Generate the shareable link and the code that comes after `https://drive.google.com/open?id=`, it should be a long code (like `3tlxSE__5eL3q7Zb31M3CEKHlieGWZYgM`)
3. Insert the long code at the end of `https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=`
4. Copy that link. Should look something like `https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=3tlxSE__5eL3q7Zb31M3CEKHlieGWZYgM`
5. When uploading a dataset to Kaggle, select to add a file from remote URL.
6. Insert copied URL.
7. Done!

Comment: But still getting https://imgur.com/a/B6zcxaX

Comment: And there is no error code whatsoever from Kaggle?

Comment: Have you ever tried it yourself? It does not work at all!

Answer (score 5):

Use `gdown` to directly download your google drive file into your session every time. The download speed is pretty high so it wont take much time.

```
!gdown https://drive.google.com/uc?id=YOUR_FILE_ID
```

The file id can obtained by the method described in the previous answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the solution that works every time and very efficiently.

A) Case of file

```
import torchvision  
torchvision.datasets.utils.download_file_from_google_drive(file_id, root, filename=None, md5=None)
```

This download a Google Drive file and place it in root.
Args:
- file_id (str): id of file to be downloaded
- root (str): Directory to place downloaded file in
- filename (str, optional): Name to save the file under. If None, use the id of the file.
- md5 (str, optional): MD5 checksum of the download. If None, do not check

B) Case of folder

1.launch google colab and log into your google drive account.
2. zip the folder :
%cd /content/drive/"My drive"/.../my_folder
! zip -r archive_name.zip my_folder

So you can download this zip file with torchvision wherever you want (filename=archive_name.zip), and unzip it with :
! unzip archive_name.zip -d my_folder

Answer (score 2):

This works for me, `pip install gdown` won't work in Kaggle so follow this:

```
!conda install -y gdown
!gdown https://drive.google.com/uc?id=ID_HERE
```

======================= or ==================

```
!conda install -y gdown 
import gdown 
url = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?id=ID_HERE' 
output = 'myfile.zip'
gdown.download(url, output)
```

Your google drive id can be found from shared link